# How to convert the output of mypy`reveal_locals()` to correct typing syntax in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Given the following script:

```py
# check.py
a = [
    ('a',),
    ('b1', 'b2'),
    ('x',),
]

reveal_locals()
```

running with:

```
mypy check.py
```

returns

```
check.py:7: note: Revealed local types are:
check.py:7: note:     a: builtins.list[builtins.tuple*[builtins.str]]
```

I'm wondering how I should then annotate for this type, if i wanted to have some:

```py
def f(a : TypeHere) -> None: 
    print(a)

f(a = [ ('a',), ('b1', 'b2'), ('x',) ] )
```

Where `a = [ ('a',), ('b1', 'b2'), ('x',) ]` is a list of tuples that have 1 or more strings.

Comment: What about `List[Tuple[str, ...]]`?

Answer (score 1):

When you're handling tuple of unknown sizes, type checker expects the syntax like `Tuple[<type>, ...]` and when the number of elements in tuple is already known example `response: typing.Tuple[int str] = (200, 'OK']`, the syntax is straight forward.

In your case, the number of items in the tuple is different, `Tuple[str, ...]` should work.

```
import typing

def f(a : typing.List[typing.Tuple[str, ...]]) -> None: 
    print(a)

f(a = [ ('a',), ('b1', 'b2'), ('x',) ] )
```